# Recreating "multiClassSummary" statistics from final model confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret, roc

Below is a random forest built on the three-outcome iris dataset using Zach Mayer's `multiClassSummary` function in caret:

```
require('caret')

data(iris)
ir.dat <- iris

tc<-trainControl("repeatedcv", repeats=5, num=2,
             selectionFunction="oneSE",
             returnData=T, classProbs = T, 
             summaryFunction=multiClassSummary, 
             savePredictions = T)

ir.train <- train(Species ~ .,
              data = ir.dat,
              method = "rf",
              trControl = tc)


## Results

ir.train$finalModel$confusion

               setosa versicolor virginica class.error
    setosa         50          0         0        0.00
    versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
    virginica       0          4        46        0.08

ir.train$bestTune
ir.train$results[1,c(4,6:7)]      

    Accuracy Mean_Sensitivity Mean_Specificity
    0.952            0.952            0.976
```

Now, I want to understand how these marginal statistics are calculated from the model's confusion matrix (or if they are calculated from the given confusion matrix at all). I know the formulas for each of the performance metrics, they are:

```
Sensitivity = sum(True Positive)/sum(Condition Positive)
Specificity= sum(True Negative)/sum(Condition Negative)
Accuracy = Sensitivity  + Specificity // sum(Total Population)
```

Also, I know that the `multiClassSummary` function uses a one-vs-all approach for calculating these marginal statistics when there are more than two outcome categories. However, when I try to recreate the calculations by hand from the given confusion matrix, my results are not the same. For example, I calculate:

```
Sensitivity = (50/50) + (47/50) + (46/50) = 2.86/3 = 0.9533
Specificity = (50/50) + (47/50) + (46/50) = 2.86/3 = 0.9533
Accuracy = Sensitivity + Specificity//150 = 0.9533
```

In my calculations each class takes a "turn" as being the positive and negative outcome. Obviously, these results don't match the output from the model, nor do they make a lot of sense being that they all have the same value. Can anyone shed some light on how these marginal statistics are calculated from the model confusion matrix in a multiClass situation?

Comment: Not really about programming, you should ask this at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Note that `ir.train$finalModel$confusion` is generated by the `randomForest` package using the  OOB statistics and is not directly relation to the confusion matrix used by `ir.train$results`. That is based on the external resampling procedure.

> Can anyone shed some light on how these marginal statistics are calculated from the model confusion matrix in a multiClass situation?

Sure!

```
> multiClassSummary ## Edited for space
function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{
  ## <snip>
  has_class_probs <- all(lev %in% colnames(data))
  if (has_class_probs) {
    lloss <- mnLogLoss(data = data, lev = lev, model = model)
    requireNamespaceQuietStop("ModelMetrics")
    prob_stats <- lapply(levels(data[, "pred"]), function(x) {
      obs <- ifelse(data[, "obs"] == x, 1, 0)
      prob <- data[, x]
      AUCs <- try(ModelMetrics::auc(obs, data[, x]), silent = TRUE)
      return(AUCs)
    })
    roc_stats <- mean(unlist(prob_stats))
  }
  CM <- confusionMatrix(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])
  if (length(levels(data[, "pred"])) == 2) {
    class_stats <- CM$byClass
  }
  else {
    class_stats <- colMeans(CM$byClass)
    names(class_stats) <- paste("Mean", names(class_stats))
  }
  overall_stats <- if (has_class_probs) 
    c(CM$overall, logLoss = lloss, ROC = roc_stats)
  else CM$overall
  if (length(levels(data[, "pred"])) > 2) 
    names(overall_stats)[names(overall_stats) == "ROC"] <- "Mean_AUC"

  ## <snip>
}
```